# Problem with List box count in asp.net website

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagridview, listbox

```
  <asp:ListBox ID="ListBoxMembers" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple"
 DataValueField="FirstName"></asp:ListBox>
```

I have this list box inside a pop up, When the user selects multiple user and click save button this is executed

```
int countSelected = ListBoxMembers.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(i => i.Selected).Count();
        string groupName = txt_GroupName.Text;
        var selectedNames = ListBoxMembers.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(i => i.Selected).Select(i => i.Value).ToList();
        foreach(var FirstName in selectedNames)
        {
         Query
         }
```

Here, the countSelected and selectedNames is always 0. where am i going wrong.
I databind the listbox

Comment: Do you use Databinding to fill the Box?

Comment: Is ViewState enabled? How are you binding the data and the handler that runs this code?

Comment: Can you post how you are binding ?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you databind on Postbacks too so the list gets repopulated before your event handler executes.